# How to draw jbox-2d in slick2d

Tags: java, box2d, jbox2d

I am trying to implement the Box2D "Hello, world" (falling box program in the manual), but can't figure out how to draw the shapes in the right spot. I believe the draw- or fillRect functions of slick2D take two corners, but I'm not sure how the Box2D coordinate system works. Anyone have any experience here?